# How to authorization my own flask api in azure ad using python?

Tags: python, flask, azure-active-directory, adal

I want to use azure ad to authorized my flask api, but get some trouble.

What I do like this:

1. Create a web app named `sample-demo` in azure ad Sign-on URL is `http://127.0.0.1:5000`
2. Update App ID URI `https://{my_tenant}/sample-demo`
3. Create a secret in keys

And my python code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import adal


# AUTHORITY_HOST_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'
AUTHORITY_HOST_URL = 'https://management.core.windows.net'
APP_AAD_TENANT = 'xxxxxxxxx'
APP_OAUTH_ID = 'xxxxxxx'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxx'
AUTHORITY_URL = '{}/{}'.format(AUTHORITY_HOST_URL, APP_AAD_TENANT)
RESOURCES = 'https://mtwoai.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/v1/health'
# RESOURCES = 'http:127.0.0.1:5000'

auth_context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL, validate_authority=False)
token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(RESOURCES, client_id=APP_OAUTH_ID,
                                                                    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
print(token_response)
print(token_response['accessToken'])
```

Comment: What error do you receive? Though I can say immediately your Authority is wrong. It should be the one you have commented out + your tenant id so e.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id-goes-here`. The resource should be the client id (app id) or the app ID URI of the API you are trying to get a token for.

Comment: @juunas When I use `https://login.microsoftonline.com` as AUTHORITY_HOST_URL get `The application named xxx was not found in the tenant named xxx`. And use `https://management.core.windows.net` as AUTHORITY_HOST_URL get `The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription`